# Resize a gwt canvas visible field, but not its content?

Tags: java, gwt, java-canvas

I have a website where I want to integrate a GWT canvas in the main layer.
When I resize the browser window, I want the canvas "visible area" to resize accordingly, BUT not it's content. Somehow like in google maps where I just can see portions of what has been drawn.

```
canvas.setSize(..)
canvas.setCoordinateSpaceHeight(..);
canvas.setCoordinateSpaceWidth(..);
```

What do I have to set in order to

- always resize the canvas according to the browser window
- not having it's content resized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three properties.

You want to `setSize` to resize the canvas, and you want to make the *coordinate space* (the "inner size" of the canvas) the same as its size (its "external size"), or within the same ratio as before the resize.

If you start with a 300×200 canvas with a 300×200 coordinate space (so that a pixel in `Context2D` maps to a CSS pixel) and you need to resize the canvas to 600×400, then set you want to set the coordinate space to 600×400 too to keep the *1 canvas pixel == 1 CSS pixel* ratio.